# I want to enable matrix variable but it shows me the message

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
"<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>    
   <context:component-scan base-package="Controllers" />"
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 18 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appDispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid;
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 59; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'enable-matrix-variables' is not allowed to appear in element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.
```

Comment: What Spring Framework version are you using ?

Comment: @ Serge Ballesta 'Spring 3.2.4'

Comment: 'please give the ans'

Comment: It looks like in 3.2, it writes `<mvc:annotation-driven enableMatrixVariables="true"/>` (but I could not test ...)

Comment: No, not working , I have got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could confirm the correct writing under Spring 3.2 is `<mvc:annotation-driven enableMatrixVariables="true" >`

Here is an extract of a working xml file for Spring Framework 3.2.4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven enableMatrixVariables="true" >
```

Note the references to 3.2 schemas